# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am developing a Flask application that performs CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations on a MongoDB database for a User resource using a REST API.

Here is my code to insert data into mongodb

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo 

app = Flask(__name__)
mongodb_client = PyMongo(app, uri="mongodb+srv://xyzzzz:xyzzzz@cluster0.iq7ljbn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = mongodb_client.db

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user_collection = db.users
    user_collection.insert({'name' : 'Cristina'})
    return '<h1>Added a User!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error

```
^C(venv) (base) Sparshs-MacBook-Pro:server sparshbohra$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2023-03-20 19:54:25,150] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/corider/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/corider/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/corider/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/corider/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/corider/server/app.py", line 11, in index
    user_collection = db.users
                      ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2023 19:54:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

There seems to be a problem in connecting flask to mongo using pymongo. I also previously tried to manually create a collection to insert my data in, but was met with the similar NoneType object error. What should be done?

PS: i'm using a fake user and password in the connection string for the purpose of asking this online.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quickstart):

> Previous versions of Flask-PyMongo required that the MongoDB URI contained a database name; as of 2.2, this requirement is lifted. If there is no database name, the db attribute will be None.

So basically, you're missing your db name in the uri

Comment: Can you tell me what the connection string would look like? If i use: uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/xyzzzz", it gives me the following error: TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: Well, your URI is now OK. Your code is failing because the `Collection` [object](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html) does not have an `insert` method. Try with `insert_one` instead.

Comment: The line 'user_collection = db.users' still gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users' after changing to insert_one